# SDL + OpenGL requires MSVCR90.dll and still gives error

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, mingw, sdl

So I was going to make a SDL + OpenGL project, with MinGW. But for some reason it still depends of a MSVCR90.dll which I find a little odd. So I tried to find a copy of the dll on my computer and copied into my bin folder. Now it gives me this nasty little error:

[image]

And here is my code and compile settings:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

SDL_Surface * screen;

GLuint loadImage(string path)
{
    GLuint texture;
    GLint nop;
    GLenum texture_format;
    SDL_Surface * sdlimage = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    if (sdlimage)
    {
        if ((sdlimage->w & (sdlimage->w - 1)) != 0)
        {
            printf("warning: %s's width is not a power of 2\n", path.c_str());
        }
        if ((sdlimage->h & (sdlimage->h - 1)) != 0)
        {
            printf("warning: %s's height is not a power of 2\n", path.c_str());
        }

        nop = sdlimage->format->BitsPerPixel;
        if (nop == 4)
        {
            if (sdlimage->format->Rmask == 0x000000FF) texture_format = GL_RGBA;
            else texture_format = GL_BGRA;
        } else if (nop == 3)
        {
            if (sdlimage->format->Rmask == 0x0000FF) texture_format = GL_RGB;
            else texture_format = GL_BGR;
        } else
        {
            printf("Invalid byte format on image %s", path.c_str());
            exit(1);
        }
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); //Make sure it doesn't blur
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); //In both shrinking and stretching situations
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nop, sdlimage->w, sdlimage->h, 0, texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sdlimage->pixels);
        SDL_FreeSurface(sdlimage);
        return texture;
    } else
    {
        printf("Could not loud %s: %s\n", path.c_str(), SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }
}

void drawTexture( GLuint texture )
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D , texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i( 0 , 0 );
        glVertex2f( 0 , 0 );

        glTexCoord2i( 1 , 0 );
        glVertex2f( 16 , 0 );

        glTexCoord2i( 1 , 1 );
        glVertex2f( 16 , 32 );

        glTexCoord2i( 0 , 1 );
        glVertex2f( 0 , 32 );
    glEnd();
}

void shutdown(void)
{
    SDL_Quit();
}

void init()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) //Loads SDL
    {
        printf("Error could not initialize SDL!");
        exit(1);
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1); //Double buffer for openGL
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_OPENGL); //Setup screen size
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //2d textures
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //Background colour will be black
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480); // Setup a viewport that matches our resolution
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Clear the colours
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Setup our projection
    glLoadIdentity(); //Load a new one
    glOrtho(0.0f, 640, 480, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); //Make our view matches our resolution
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Go into modelview
    glLoadIdentity(); //Load a new one
    atexit(shutdown);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    init();
    GLuint text = loadImage("rmb.png");
    drawTexture(text);
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    glDeleteTextures( 1, &text );
    return 0;
}
```

Compile settings:

```
g++ -o bic.exe "src\\game.o" -lmingw32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image
```

Comment: You didn't ask any particular question, but if you're asking how to properly install that dll...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993560

Comment: DLL problem? Always try Dependency Walker first.

Comment: It's probably because SDL depends on it.

Comment: Once you've found out which DLL depends on it you probably want to get a version of that built with MinGW too.

Comment: After installing Visual Studio 2008 redistributable the dll msvcr90.dll is still not present except from that single dll I found that comes from another program. And I used Dependency Walker on my .exe, and it turns out that I'm missing a IESHIMS.dll